# GMail Interaction with .Net

Tags: .net, gmail, user-interaction

We have a custom line of business .Net WinForms application that currently exposes the Microsoft Outlook Interop assemblies to create a new message, add the recipient(s), subject line, and attachment(s), then leaves the new message (Outlook) window open for the user to complete and send themselves.  Our company is migrating to GMail hosted email soon, and Outlook will not be supported, nor even installed, as a client application.

My question: is there a known way to programmatically open GMail in a browser with a new message created, with recipients and attachments pre-loaded for the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Outlook works fine with Gmail.

Comment: Yes, but Outlook will no longer be supported, so it's not an option. In the end, neither Outlook, nor any other thick-client email client, will be installed on any workstation.